# Argparse: unser input

Tags: python, networking, argparse, prediction

I am building a Network for predicting. In which, user need to puts 2 input to get the predicted values.
Currently, I used this command:

`Density = float(input("Density Ratio (%): "))` # User input

`Ra = float(input("Surface Roughness- Ra (um): "))` # User input

These values were put during running cmd /...script.py

However, I want to use the Argparse pack to input the mentioned values at the begining, like cmd  / ... script.py 10, 20, for example.

What should I do for that purpose?

This is my code, required values locate at line 42, 43: https://gist.github.com/TonyS0n/66c8205be2e421fa0bee8d07112ec2f9

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can simply use [argparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) for it.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process input data')
parser.add_argument('--density', type=int, dest='density',
                    help='Density Ratio (%)')
parser.add_argument('--ra', type=int, dest='ra', 
                    help='Surface Roughness- Ra (um)')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Dear sir. Thank you very much.
I follow your suggestion, but when I run cmd by : ...script.py 90 20 I got error:unrecognized arguments. 
I am sorry because I am a newbie of python.
My modified code here : https://gist.github.com/TonyS0n/66c8205be2e421fa0bee8d07112ec2f9

Comment: there is missing "import argparse" you can put it as separate line on top of your script.

Comment: The problem was solved. Thank you very much for your recommendation :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for such a simple use case would be to use `sys.argv`.

After `from sys import argv` you can access the `argv` object, which is a ordered list of all script arguments starting with the script name as the first argument.